# User ranking system

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This new code works for me, but not quite, the problem now is that all users have the sameness ranking, all have 1°

```
 <?php
 mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_db) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, username, Wins, Loses, Draws, (Wins + Loses) AS points FROM users WHERE username='$_GET[user]' ORDER BY points DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if( !$result ){
  echo 'SQL Query Failed';
 }else{
  $rank = 0;
$last_score = false;
$rows = 0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
$rows++;
if( $last_score!= $row['Wins'] ){
  $last_score = $row['Wins'];
  $rank = $rows;
}
echo "rank ".$rank." is ".$row['Name']." with point ".$row['Wins']."";
}
}
?>
```

I NEED

```
Example:
 ID username Wins Loses
 1    demo    12   12   RANKIG= 1°
 2    demo2   1    3    RANKIG= 2°
```

Comment: Side note(s), don't use `mysql_*` anymore, it's removed as of phpv7 and don't do `...WHERE username='$_GET[user]'...` this is a security issue (sql injection). Take a look at `PDO` and bind values/parameters instead.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how the code should be?

Comment: And now change your password

Comment: You have a problem that only `points` column is displayed?

Comment: want it to be the result of user ranking, just gives me the result of the sum of Wins + Loses

Comment: From Rasclatt answer, if you are running an earlier version you can prevent / limit the chance getting the sql injection with "mysqli_real_esc_string" function. As appose to handling the logic in the query isn't bad practice, my advice or way would be to extract the values and then handle the logic in the code it self. Using 'AS' operator after your query should help overcome your current problem.

Comment: Are you missing an AS?  SELECT foo AS bar.

Comment: edit the post with the example to understand me

Answer (score 0):

Try your query as:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT ID, Name, username, Wins, Loses, Draws, (Wins + Loses) AS points, count(points) AS Ranking FROM `users` WHERE username='$_GET[user]' ORDER BY CONVERT(points, INT) DESC");
```

Comment: try using 'points' without double quotes? Updated answer to reflect change. I can't replicate this on my machine due to my apache is not setup on this machine. :/ Hope that helps, some more advice look in debugging your query with some mysql_error handling.

Comment: you think you can help me on my server? please

Comment: What you give in url parameter that u get in $_GET['user']
What is it value?

Because the @Erick answer should work

Comment: I was asking for exacly value in example. Maybe you pass bad value to the $_GET['user'], because the sql query above should work

Comment: I think they did not understand me, do not want it to be the result of the sum of Wins + Loses, I want the result of rankig 1°, 2°, 3°...

Comment: I want the user ranking

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, username, Wins, Loses, Draws, (Wins + Loses) AS points FROM Models WHERE username='$_GET[user]'ORDER BY points DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if( !$result ){
  echo 'SQL Query Failed';
}else{
  $rank = 0;
  $last_score = false;
  $rows = 0;
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    $rows++;
    if( $last_score!= $row['Wins'] ){
      $last_score = $row['Wins'];
      $rank = $rows;
    }
    echo "rank ".$rank." is ".$row['Name']." with point ".$row['Wins']."";
  }
}` just need it for a user

Comment: will update the post with a new code, it is better but does not work for every user

Comment: Update post with a portion of current results.